# How to sort an NSArray full of EKCalendars by the title

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've got a NSArray with a bunch of EKCalendar Objects in it. I need to sort them alphabetically. I'm new to selectors but I think I need something like...

```
NSArray *array = [otherArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector('localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:title')];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it that way. Instead do the following:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    EKCalendar *cal1 = (EKCalendar *)obj1;
    EKCalendar *cal2 = (EKCalendar *)obj2;
    return [cal1.title localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:cal2.title];
}];
```

Edit - an explanation:

`-sortedArrayUsingComparator` takes what is called a 'block' (an inline function) that must return an `NSComparisonResult`. All the hard work is done for you, as your block is run for as many pairs of objects as is needed to establish the correct order. Then all this does is cast each object type to an `EKCalendar` and then compare the two titles. You can adapt this to work for any type of object.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [NSMutableArray array];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByTitleAsc = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES] autorelease];
[sortDescriptors addObject:sortByTitleAsc];
NSArray *arraySortedByTitle = [otherArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: Thanks I've not started to get my head around selectors yet.

Comment: That only works for key-value coding compliant classes, which EKCalendar is not.

Comment: No problem :) sobox, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't want to use a selector, you want to use a key path, which requires a sort descriptor. You can't append an arbitrary property name to a selector name. The selector must exactly match the method name. Otherwise you just get nothing (nil/NULL/0) for the selector.

id sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:YES]]];

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness and and timeliness, here’s the Swift 4 version:

```
let store = EKEventStore()
let calendars = store.calendars(for: .event)
let calendarsSorted = calendars.sorted { $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1.title) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
```

By the way, please don’t forget to request access to the store by calling `store.requestAccess(to:completion:)` before accessing the store’s data.